# Swift - horizontal scroll collection view cells (automatically and manually)

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionviewcell

In my app I have used AVPlayer to play video. By using the following function I am getting frames from the video in each second (if video length is 2 minutes(120 seconds) I am getting 120 frames). This frames are stored in an array **videoFrames**

```
var videoFrames = [UIImage]()
 func generateFrames(url: NSURL, fromTime: Float64) {
        let asset: AVAsset = AVAsset(url: url as URL)
        let assetImgGenerate: AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        assetImgGenerate.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
        assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let time: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(fromTime, 600)
        var img: CGImage?
        do {
            img = try assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        } catch {
        }
        if img != nil {
            let frameImg: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: img!)
            videoFrames.append(frameImg)
        } else {
//            return nil
        }
    }
```

This video frames are placed in a horizontal scrolling UICollectionView like this[image]

> Now I need to move the UICollectionView cells automatically from right
>   to left and also allow the user(if wishes) to scroll manually.
>   (Exactly the same functionality when you play video in iPhone/iPod
>   etc)

I found this code...

```
func autoScroll () {
    let co = collectionView.contentOffset.x
    let no = co + 1

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.01, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self]() -> Void in
        self?.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: no, y: 0)
    }) { [weak self](finished) -> Void in
        self?.autoScroll()
    }
}
```

but before finishing video the auto scroll finishes. I can't determine what should be the value of **withDuration:** parameter in **UIView.animate()**. Also if I add this **autoScroll ()** function I can't scroll the UICollectionView cells manually. But I need both automatically & manually.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: As to the value for `withDuration` I'd try a different approach. Since each of your cells represents a 1-second frame I'd make the duration of animation to be 1 second, and change the value of `no` to be `co + cell.width`. So this method gets called each second and scrolls the collection by one cell each time.

Comment: thank you. I did this but it is not smooth. It seems after passing one cell it stops for a millisecond and then starts again. Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: There should be a version of `UIView.animete()` without the `options` parameter. With `curveEaseInOut` your animation gets gradually faster and the slower in its duration. Without it, it will be linear, so the pause may disappear or be less noticeable.

Comment: stil getting the same result with...
`UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: { [weak self]() -> Void in
            self?.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: no, y: 0)
        }) { [weak self](finished) -> Void in
            self?.autoScroll()
        }`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is initially create a variable called *index* with value 0. Now create a `Timer` function that will fire every 1 second and repeat itself, inside the selector for the `Timer` just use `scrollToItem` method of the collection view and keep incrementing the *index* variable.

Now when the user begins scrolling in the `collectionView` just invalidate the timer and calculate the *index* based on the scroll amount. After the scrolling, restart the timer again. Remember to move the video to the appropriate location as well!

**Edit:**

```
var timer : Timer!

var index = 0

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated:Bool){

     //call super here

     timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(handleTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func handleTimer(){

    index += 1

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)

    main.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: thanks...some code snippet would be a great help ...if you can @Rikh

Comment: I wrote this        `func scrollToNext() {
        var index = 0;
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0);
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true);
        index += 1
    }`
but didn't work

Comment: I added it in the edit. In your code you are redeclaring the index so it becomes 0 everytime and are incrementing the counter **after** the scrolling so it has no effect. Have a look at the edit.

Comment: thank you. I did this but it is not smooth. It seems after passing one cell it stops for a millisecond and then starts again. Any idea how to solve this ?